# In CSS "mobile only screen" isn't applied on main page, but does on sub-pages

Tags: html, css, mobile

On my index I have images with mouse hover text on top displayed on desktop. On index, using mobile, I have used media queries but it doesn't work. Visit the issue page http://pavelrozman.com

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
```

On my sub-page the code executes correctly on mobile, displaying the text over top of the image instead of using hover. See here http://pavelrozman.com/projects/ I compared the code between both pages and they seem identical. Can't think of why.

Answer (score 0):

On your projects page you include  `projects.css` that changes the opacity back to 1 for the divs within the screen range.

On the home page you only include `style.css`  which doesn't include changing the opacity back to 1.

eg: Look at the class `wyomingx` as found on the home page, it is not included in your media CSS

This should fix your issue.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 .wyomingx,
 .coloradox,
 .mainex,
 .dc2x,
 .nyx,
 .signsx {
    opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

You can see here for the 3 divs you did include that you have errors: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpavelrozman.com%2Fassets%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en